# Idiomatic Java: constraining data

Tags: java, coding-style

Playing with a simple Java `Point` class where I would like to constrain the X and Y values to be doubles that must be in the range -10 to 10, inclusive. I've written some code, but it's been years since I've written java and I would like to know if this is how it would be written in modern Java:

```
public class Point {
    private double x;
    private double y;

    public Point(double x, double y) {
        constrain("x", x);
        constrain("y", y);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    // is there a cleaner/shorter way of handling this, such as a direct way of declaring a
    // subtype of double that I could use in method signatures?
    protected static void constrain(String name, double val) {
        if ( val < -10 || val > 10 ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(name + " must be between -10 and 10");
        }
    }

    public double getX() { return x; }

    public void setX(double x) {
        constrain("x", x);
        this.x = x;
    }

    public double getY() { return y; }

    public void setY(double y) {
        constrain("y", y);
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ("[" + x + "," + y + "]"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably one for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.  But FWIW, this is probably most idiomatically solved nowadays using Guava Preconditions.

Comment: This may be opinion-based and may be good for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: No, no subtypes yet. And don't repeat the contrain calls. In the constructor: this.x = x; replace by setX( x );

Comment: Mr Naso: An interesting issue is how to instantiate Point with variable checks, and I mean not just the limit. 1.8 has "lightweight" code objects, i.e., lambdas, and one might use that *if needed*. (Hi, old Perl hacker!)

Comment: Did your code compile and yeild the expected results? If so, what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably how I'd do it:

```
public class Point
{

    private static final double X_MIN = -10.0, X_MAX = 10.0;
    private static final double Y_MIN = -10.0, Y_MAX = 10.0;

    private double x, y;

    public Point(double x, double y) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        setX(x);
        setY(y);
    }

    public double getX()
    {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY()
    {
        return y;
    }

    public void setX(double x) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        if (x < X_MIN || x > X_MAX)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("X out of range.");
        }

        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(double y) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        if (y < Y_MIN || y > Y_MIN)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Y out of range");
        }

        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("[%.1f,%.1f]", x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: You lost the check in the constructor.

Comment: @laune Thanks for pointing that out; overlooked that. Answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

If the X and Y values are always from the same domain then you could encapsulate them in a class that does the checking for you:

```
class Coord {
    private final double scalarValue;
    public Coord(double scalarValue) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (Math.abs(scalarValue) > MAX_COORD) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Coordinate out of range");
        }
        this.scalarValue = scalarValue;
    }
    public double getScalar() {
        return scalarValue;
    }
}
```

That puts the check in one place and allows you to expand coordinate functionality in the future without messing up your Point class. It also explicitly makes coordinates immutable which is likely to be a good idea (depending on use case).

Then your point constructor becomes:

```
public Point(Coord x, Coord y);
```